# Postgresql dump not going to correct database upon importing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2

My goal is to import the .sql dump from my server into the project_devel database.  I've run into a frustrating problem where the -d [databasename] option seems to be ignored when I load data from a .sql file.  Instead (as you can see about 12 lines down into the output), the .sql file may be telling the importer to import into another database.  Any clue on why this is happening and how to force the data to go into the database I specify with -d?

I finally put a band-aid on it by changing my development database name in database.yml to project_prod, as my goal here is just to load the production data locally and debug something.

Command I use to import:

```
YeastFlakes:newproject new$ psql -h /tmp -d project_devel -f prod_dump_2013-02-07_09-00.sql
```

Output:

```
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "new".
    SET
    SET
    SET
    psql:prod_dump_2013-02-07_09-00.sql:15: ERROR:  role "project" already exists
    ALTER ROLE
    psql:prod_dump_2013-02-07_09-00.sql:17: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists
    ALTER ROLE
    psql:prod_dump_2013-02-07_09-00.sql:19: ERROR:  role "replication" already exists
    ALTER ROLE
    psql:prod_dump_2013-02-07_09-00.sql:31: ERROR:  database "project_prod" already exists
    REVOKE
    REVOKE
    GRANT
    GRANT
    You are now connected to database "project_prod" as user "new".
    SET
    SET
    SET
    SET
    SET
    SET
    CREATE EXTENSION
    COMMENT
    SET
    SET
    SET
    psql:prod_dump_2013-02-07_09-00.sql:85: ERROR:  relation "active_admin_comments" already exists
    ALTER TABLE
    psql:prod_dump_2013-02-07_09-00.sql:99: ERROR:  relation "active_admin_comments_id_seq" already exists
```

output continues for a while longer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fairly clearly says at the top of your output:

```
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "new".
...
You are now connected to database "project_prod" as user "new".
```

If you look at the first twenty or so lines of your backup I don't suppose you see anything looking like a "connect" command? Possibly to database "postgresql" as user "new", followed by another to database "project_prod" again as user "new"?

Oh - and if you're not going to actually look inside the file, there's no point in dumping as raw SQL. Might as well use the "custom" format which is compressed and gives you the option of restoring individual/selected elements with pg_restore. See the extensive and detailed manuals for details.

Comment: Ok, so looking in the sql file it does clearly have commands to basically do what it wants in terms of creating a database, connecting as a user, calling it what it wants.  I'm new to psql backing up and restoring, so wasn't sure why the commands I issued were getting overridden, but that makes perfect sense that if they're written directly in the file, it's gonna happen.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 4):

The [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/backup-dump.html) seems to take a very simple approach to SQL dump/restore;

```
Dump: 

$ pg_dump dbname > outfile

Restore:

$ psql dbname < infile
```

Any particular reason not to use that method?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I ran into an issue where psql would tell me the outfile does not exist (which of course it doesn't, it's a new file), and when I create it then try to write to it with these commands, the file doesn't actually get anything written to it.  These are the docs I was going off of: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: some links i found most helpful http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/functions-misc.html, http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-backup-postgresql-databases.html